# How to create custom URLs for new users using Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, react-redux

I have a React/Redux application that creates and saves new users under Firebase as `/users/<uid>`

However, I also want to have each user have a custom URL for their profile pages, like `domain.com/users/john-david` or `domain.com/users/john-david-1343` (if the original `/users/john-david` is already taken.)

What's the best way to do this?

My problem is that I was going to store users under `/users/<firstname-lastname-hash>` in Firebase, but that seems like a bad idea to store them under anything besides uid (is this true?).

But also, if I don't do that, then how do I maintain `/users/<uid>` in Firebase, while creating new usernames that account for duplicates, and searching if the user exists when visiting `domain.com/users/john-david-123`

Here is some sample code of where the new user gets saved to Firebase

```
export function saveUser (data, user) {
  let username = data.username
  return ref.child(`users/${user.uid}/info`)
    .set({
      email: user.email,
      firstname: data.firstName,
      lastname: data.lastName,
      admin: false,
      // for /users/<username>
      username: username,
      uid: user.uid
    })
    .then(() => user)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general we say you should store data in Firebase how you intend to view it, and there's no reason in particular that you **must** use the UID as your primary key when storing users. What you might want to is:

1. Store user data in `/users/${username}` as you mentioned, including a `uid` field.
2. When a user signs up, generate the `firstname-lastname` slug and store in `/uids/${uid} = username`.

This way you have a simple way to map from UID to user and vice-versa. The downside here is that once you bake a username into your data structure, you should probably never let them change their username.

Alternatively, you could reverse my suggestion and store `/usernames/${username} = uid` and `/users/${uid}`. This makes it easier to rename usernames, but requires that you do an extra lookup to go from username to data.

Comment: so simple i want to hit myself. great answer and what i ended up going with.